# $ \ ( \forall p \in \mathbb{Z})( \exists q \in \mathbb{N})[(p^2 = 2q^2) \implies (p^2 + q^2 > 4)]$

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Question:

Is the following statement true or false:

$ \ ( \forall p \in \mathbb{Z})( \exists q \in \mathbb{N})[(p^2 = 2q^2) \implies (p^2 + q^2 > 4)]$

My attempt:

The statement is true because the premise of the "if then$ statement is false.

Comment: Do you take $\mathbb{N}$ to include $0$?

Comment: No. Its not considered a natural number

Comment: Is my argument valid if I say that since the premise false the whole statement is true?

Comment: Yes, as long as you are able to prove that the premise is always false.

Comment: @JohnGriffin The 'if' part of a conditional is typically called its *antecedent*, not premise.

Answer (score 0):

If $0\in\mathbb{N}$, then it's false with $p=q=0$.

Otherwise, suppose $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $q\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfies $p^2=2q^2$.
Then $q\geq 1$ implies that $p^2\geq 4$ and $q^2>0$. Consequently 
$p^2+q^2 > 4$. This proves the statement.

As you pointed out, instead of doing the short argument above we could have noticed that it's impossible to have $p^2=2q^2$ for $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q\in\mathbb{N}$. Indeed, if $p^2=2q^2$ for $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$, $q\ne0$, then
$$
2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2}
$$
implies that $\sqrt{2} = p/q$ is rational.